# Remote Desktop disconnects after reaching "Estimating connection quality..."

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, remote-desktop

I'm connecting to a Windows 8 machine from a Windows 7 machine.  When I try to RDP in to the machine, it prompts me for my credentials, then zooms through the process of connecting until it reaches "Estimating connection quality."

After a few seconds, it disconnects without giving any message whatsoever and returns me to the Remote Desktop Connection connect window.  No error message, no popups, nothing.  It just silently fails to connect after reaching "Estimating connection quality."

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: have you installed the RDP8.0 update for Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, that update is installed.  I used to be able to connect to the computer, but today or yesterday that changed.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the Windows 8 machine and the problem went away.  Yay!